# Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Project Creation Failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have been having this problem for some time and it is frustrating. OK, so whenever I launch VS and start a new C++ project, I get the old same message, "project creation failed". I have absolutely no idea on how to fix this. I have searched around a bit, but nothing has really helped.

I run Windows 7 64 bit operating system.

Some info you guys may be wondering:

I have reinstalled this multiple times. No luck.
I Have tried on Visual C++ Express (downloaded properly from Mircorsoft). No luck.
I have tried pirated software. No luck.
This has been happening with the 2012 and 2010 products.

Comment: yes, i have re-installed multiple times. No luck :(

Comment: Is it VS2010 or VS2012? Tagged one thing, title says another. I have no insight either way, but *maybe* someone might.

Comment: It is 2012. I don't know how the tags changed!

Comment: How did you afford Ultimate? Yikes that must have been expensive, if you did actually buy it contact microsoft they will know. 

Be aware that 2012 or otherwise Visual Studio 11, has alot of little issues, if you have 2010 installed and then installed the release candidate (And maybe even full release), resource files just stopped working all together, if you have an older version you may want to try a complete uninstall of both and then a full install of the new one, or go back to 2010 until they make a service pack.

Comment: no i had this problem with VC 2010 Ultimate as well. Never worked. And yes, both of them were pirated...

Comment: You are wondering why your pirated software doesn't work? Seriously?

Comment: no this happened with the free Visual C++ software too(the one i firstly downloaded from Microsoft). I have tried on several ones.